# How to generate a random number in Matlab, to have a good scatter distribution?

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, scatter-plot

I want to generate random numbers in Matlab to have a nice distribution, but, I got only a line...

I tried with `random('HalfNormal',500,500)`, with `random('Binomial',50,rand(1,1));` and `random('Logistic',0,0.1);` but I only got something like this:

[image: The line distribution, which is bad to me]

But I need something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

UPDATE:
My data generator code, for the part one of the data:

```
R_i = 750;
R_0 = 7500;
t   = 0.75;
a   = 0.75;

for i = 1:500
    R_i   = R_i + random('HalfNormal',50,15);
    R_0     = R_0 + random('HalfNormal',500,500);
    %here is my data
    [output] = ComplexChanger(R_i,R_0,t,a,random_complex_dataset);
    %from here I can save to file or anything using the mean(abs(real(output))) and mean(abs(imag(output))), so I can generate a number from all of it, which means this is much more randomized
end

function [output] = ComplexChanger(R_i,R_0,t,a, random_complex_dataset)
    output = R_i+(R_0-R_i)./(1+(sqrt(-1).*xdata.*t).^a); %here I change the complex data with a basic Cole stuff, which is ideal to manipulate complex number, which are good to have a two dimensional vector.
end
```

Comment: Please show everything you did. I don’t understand how you got those plots from random numbers, unless you’re plotting each value against itself. See [mre]. Also explain what “a nice distribution” means. You need to be explicit about what you need. There are hundreds of “nice distributions” we could be drawing numbers from. We need to know exactly what you are after to help you on your way.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've created 2D arrays from them, that's, all.

Comment: You must have computed y from x somehow. They’re obviously correlated. Show your code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is a bit complicated, the generator is in Matlab, the plotter is in Python, but I've updated the question with the generator part.

Comment: With `R_i   = R_i + random('HalfNormal',50,15);` you add a random offset to each previous value.  Not sure what your intention with that is. Could you please clarify what you are after? This is still odd and unclear.

Comment: Also this `ComplexChanger` is strange. It increases the correlation between the two axes. What is `xdata`?

Comment: With that I only want a stable point and add random values to it, to have a center of the spread. After that I generate many complex numbers, with ColeCole function, to have an XY value of my point. From them I creating only a pair, and then I create one more, pair and so on. This for more randomization of values, based on an existing center of values.

Comment: `xdata`is just a dataset of random complex numbers, in xlsx, from the internet. Some measurements or something like that...

Comment: Well, you don’t have a stable point because you keep updating it. Each of your random values uses the previous one as the center value. And why would you add someone’s measurements into your random values? I really don’t understand the purpose of that `ComplexChanger` function. Why don’t you just generate random values with `[c_x,c_y]+randn(500,2).*[s_x,s_y]`? `c_x` being the center for the x coordinate, `s_x` the standard deviation for the x coordinate, etc. This gives an array with two columns, x and y, and 500 rows, one for each point, normally distributed.

Comment: But normal distribution still is a "line" on scatter plot, or not?

Comment: I'm using someone else's data, because I'm trying to generate random noise around it. Here isn't the point on the data, but I'm trying to understand a good noise generator, and use it, with classification algorithms.

Comment: `randn` produces normally distributed data, `rand` produces uniformly distributed data. You can do other distributions in MATLAB, but it gets more involved. These two are the simple, basic functions. These are good noise generators. If you draw a random value for x and one for y, you won't get a line, the values will be uncorrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to just use the randomized value, what you have generated with this. Don't add it to the existing value, just use it.

Also, I recommend the Uniform, binomial, half normal distributions, but with bigger values, for example: `random('HalfNormal',750,50);` if initial value is `R_i = 750;`.

So, for example, your final code can be:

```
t   = 0.75;
a   = 0.75;

for i = 1:500
    R_i   = random('HalfNormal',750,50);
    R_0   = random('HalfNormal',7500,500);
    %here is my data
    [output] = ComplexChanger(R_i,R_0,t,a,random_complex_dataset);
    %from here I can save to file or anything using the mean(abs(real(output))) and mean(abs(imag(output))), so I can generate a number from all of it, which means this is much more randomized
end

function [output] = ComplexChanger(R_i,R_0,t,a, random_complex_dataset)
    output = R_i+(R_0-R_i)./(1+(sqrt(-1).*xdata.*t).^a); %here I change the complex data with a basic Cole stuff, which is ideal to manipulate complex number, which are good to have a two dimensional vector.
end
```